# How to convert from sum to time - mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime, sum, time-format

In mysql database i've created "leave" table:

```
+--------+---------+---------+-------------+---------+-------------------------------+
|ID_LEAVE|ID_WORKER| FNAME | LNAME | BEGIN_DATE         | END_DATE             | 
+--------+---------+---------+---------+------------+--------------------+-----------
| 1      |   1     | ALAN  | MAX  |2019-03-19 07:00:00 |2019-03-20 15:00:00   | 
| 2      |   1     | ALAN  | MAX   |2019-03-21 07:00:00  |2019-03-21 15:00:00    |
+--------+---------+---------+----------------------+--------------------------------+
```

"Workers Table"

```
+----------+---------+---------+
|ID_WORKER |  FNAME  | LNAME   |
+----------+---------+----------
| 1        |  ALAN   |  MAX    |
| 2        |  MARK   |  DARK   |
+----------+---------+---------+
```

"Orders" Table:

```
+----------+--------------+---------------+
|ID_ORDER  |  DESC_ORDER  | NUMBER_ORDER  |
+----------+--------------+---------------+
| 20       |  TEST        |  TEST         |
+----------+--------------+---------------+
```

"Order_status" Table:

```
+----------+---------+---------+---------------------+-------------------+------------+
| Id_status|ID_WORKER| ID_ORDER| BEGIN_DATE          | END_DATE          | ORDER_DONE |
+----------+---------+---------+----------+------------+---------+--------------------+
| 30       |   1     |    20   |2019-03-18 06:50:35  |2019-03-18 15:21:32|  NO        |
| 31       |   1     |    20   |2019-03-20 06:44:12  |2019-03-20 15:11:23|  NO        |
| 32       |   1     |    20   |2019-03-22 06:50:20  |2019-03-22 12:22:33|  YES       |
| 33       |   2     |    20   |2019-03-18 06:45:11  |2019-03-18 15:14:45|  NO        |
| 34       |   2     |    20   |2019-03-20 06:50:22  |2019-03-20 15:10:32|  NO        |
| 35       |   2     |    20   |2019-03-22 06:54:11  |2019-03-22 11:23:45|  YES       |
+----------+---------+---------+------------+---------+-------------------+-----------+
```

What i've done:

I can to sumarize "total time" of each other workers (in order_status table) on the order including with sumarizing "leave time" from Leave table. I have selected workers (LNAME, FNAME) orders (DESC_ORDER and NUMBER_ORDER) and "TOTAL TIME" on order from each other workers correctly too. I wrote the mysql command in below:

```
SELECT workers.fname, 
       workers.lname, 
       order_statusAgg.number_order,
       workers.id_worker,
       order_statusAgg.desc_order, 
       SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(order_statusAgg.stime)) AS 'TOTAL TIME', 
       IFNULL(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(leaveAgg.vtime)),'00:00:00') AS 'LEAVE TIME'
FROM   workers 
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT leave.id_worker, time_format(SUM((datediff(leave.end_date, leave.begin_date) + 1) * (time(leave.end_date) - time(leave.begin_date))), '%H:%i:%s') AS vtime 
FROM leave
GROUP BY leave.id_worker 
) leaveAgg
               ON leaveAgg.id_worker = workers.id_worker
       LEFT JOIN (
SELECT order_status.id_worker, orders.number_order, orders.desc_order, SUM((Time_to_sec(order_status.end_date) - 
                       Time_to_sec(order_status.begin_date))) AS stime
FROM order_status
           INNER JOIN orders 
               ON orders.id_order = order_status.id_order
GROUP BY order_status.id_worker
) order_statusAgg
               ON workers.id_worker = order_statusAgg.id_worker 

WHERE  order_statusAgg.number_order LIKE 'TEST'
GROUP BY workers.id_worker
```

Then i get the result:

```
    +---------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+
    |  FNAME  | LNAME   |  NUMBER_ORDER | DESC_ORDER | TOTAL TIME | LEAVE_TIME   | 
    +---------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+
    |  ALAN   |  MARK   | TEST          | TEST       | 22:30:21   |00:00:24.000000|   
    +---------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+
    |  MARK   |  GREEN  | TEST          | TEST       | 21:19:18   |   00:00:00    |   
    +---------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+
```

But as for as Leave time is concerned is incorrect, because when i write that command:

```
    SELECT leave.id_worker, 
time_format(SUM((datediff(leave.end_date, leave.begin_date) + 1) * (time(leave.end_date) - time(leave.begin_date))), '%H:%i:%s') AS vtime 
    FROM leave
    GROUP BY leave.id_worker

+----------+---------+
|ID_WORKER |  vtime  |
+----------+---------+
| 1        | 24:00:00|
+----------+---------+
```

I've tried doing like this:

```
1) IFNULL(SUM(leaveAgg.vtime),'00:00:00') AS 'Leave time'
2) IFNULL(time_format(SUM(leaveAgg.vtime),'%H:%i:%s'),'00:00:00') AS 'Leave time'
```

But none of them didn't work.

So i need convert from count to datetime in this case

00:00:24.000000 => 24:00:00

I was serching for ideas but i haven't found a succesfull solution. Any ideas? Can someone please show what should i do or what kind of query can write? Thank you for any help!

Comment: Can you add also the content of the `order_statusAgg` and `leaveAgg` tables?

Comment: @AntoanMilkov what kind of content do you want?

Comment: @AntoanMilkov ok in `order_statusAgg` you have a query from:
 `SELECT order_status.id_worker, orders.number_order, orders.desc_order, SUM((Time_to_sec(order_status.end_date) - 
                       Time_to_sec(order_status.begin_date))) AS stime
FROM order_status
           INNER JOIN orders 
               ON orders.id_order = order_status.id_order
GROUP BY order_status.id_worker `

Comment: @AntoanMilkov in  `leaveAgg` you have:
`SELECT leave.id_worker, time_format(SUM((datediff(leave.end_date, leave.begin_date) + 1) * (time(leave.end_date) - time(leave.begin_date))), '%H:%i:%s') AS vtime 
FROM leave
GROUP BY leave.id_worker`

Comment: @AntoanMilkov `order_statusAgg` and `leaveAgg` aren't the tables they are aggregate functions!

Comment: I think your `SEC_TO_TIME` command doesn't work as your `leaveAgg.vtime` return seconds value in this format `00:00:24`. What should be the correct value for `leaveAgg.vtime` ? 24 hours?

Comment: @tcadidot0 yes it should be 24 hours (24:00:00)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT workers.fname, 
   workers.lname, 
   order_statusAgg.number_order,
   workers.id_worker,
   order_statusAgg.desc_order, 
   SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(order_statusAgg.stime)) AS 'TOTAL TIME', 
   IFNULL(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(leaveAgg.vtime)),'00:00:00') AS 'LEAVE TIME'
FROM workers 
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT leave.id_worker, SUM((datediff(leave.end_date, leave.begin_date) + 1) * (time_to_sec(time(leave.end_date)) - time_to_sec(time(leave.begin_date)))) AS vtime 
FROM leave
GROUP BY leave.id_worker) leaveAgg
           ON leaveAgg.id_worker = workers.id_worker
   LEFT JOIN (
SELECT order_status.id_worker, orders.number_order, orders.desc_order, 
SUM((Time_to_sec(order_status.end_date) - 
                   Time_to_sec(order_status.begin_date))) AS stime
FROM order_status
       INNER JOIN orders 
           ON orders.id_order = order_status.id_order
GROUP BY order_status.id_worker) order_statusAgg
           ON workers.id_worker = order_statusAgg.id_worker 
WHERE  order_statusAgg.number_order LIKE 'TEST'
GROUP BY workers.id_worker;
```

I didn't do much, I just changed this part:

`SELECT leave.id_worker, time_format(SUM((datediff(leave.end_date, leave.begin_date) + 1) * (time(leave.end_date) - time(leave.begin_date))), '%H:%i:%s') AS vtime`

to

`SELECT leave.id_worker, SUM((datediff(leave.end_date, leave.begin_date) + 1) * (time_to_sec(time(leave.end_date)) - time_to_sec(time(leave.begin_date)))) AS vtime`

in your `leaveAgg`.